# Sheaf condition for subcoverings

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

This is a refinement of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784275/sheaf-condition-for-finite-coverings/784283?noredirect=1#comment1627481_784283). Let $X$ be a space and $\mathscr{F}$ a presheaf on $X$ with values in a complete category. Let $\mathscr{U} = \{ U_i \}$ be an open covering and suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ satisfies the sheaf condition with respect to some subcovering of $\mathscr{U}$. Does $\mathscr{F}$ automatically satisfy the sheaf condition with respect to $\mathscr{U}$? If $\mathscr{F}$ is a presheaf of sets then this is an easy calculation, but what if $\mathscr{F}$ takes values in e.g. spaces, where we cannot simply check that the relevant map is injective and surjective? Ideally there would be some purely category-theoretic proof.

Comment: Like I said, there is a Yoneda-type argument that allows you to carry over the proof from $\mathbf{Set}$. If you are thinking about $(\infty, 1)$-categories then you should say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exercise in transferring proofs from $\mathbf{Set}$ to general categories via Yoneda. Here is the key lemma:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, let $\mathfrak{U}$ be a sieve on an object $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a locally small and complete category. Then a presheaf $F : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$ satisfies the sheaf condition for $\mathfrak{U}$ if and only if, for every $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$, the presheaf $\mathcal{A} (A, F) : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfies the sheaf condition for $\mathfrak{U}$.

Indeed, the sheaf condition for $\mathfrak{U}$ is just the statement that some diagram of the form
$$F (C) \to \prod_{f \in \mathfrak{U}} F (\operatorname{dom} f) \rightrightarrows \prod_{f \in \mathfrak{U}} \prod_{\operatorname{codom} g = \operatorname{dom} f} F (\operatorname{dom} g)$$
is an equaliser. The functor $\mathcal{A} (A, -) : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves limits, so $\mathcal{A} (A, F) : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfies the sheaf condition for $\mathfrak{U}$ if $F$ does. Conversely, if $\mathcal{A} (A, F) : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfies the sheaf condition for $\mathfrak{U}$ for *all* $A$, then we may deduce that the above diagram is indeed an equaliser diagram, because the functors $\mathcal{A} (A, -) : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Set}$  are jointly conservative.

---

There are more conceptual proofs, but they ultimately rely on proving it for presheaves of sets first. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is *small* and $\mathcal{A}$ is complete. Then, given a presheaf $F : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$, we can take the right Kan extension along the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ and get a limit-preserving functor $F : [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$. Here is a fact:

> $F : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$ is a sheaf if and only if $F : [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{A}$ factors (up to isomorphism) through the associated sheaf functor $a : [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}; \mathbf{Set})$.

It can be shown that the associated sheaf functor $a : [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}; \mathbf{Set})$ is (up to equivalence) the universal functor that sends covering sieves $\mathfrak{U} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{C}(-, C)$ to isomorphisms. You can even check this just for a *suitable* generating families of covering sieves. The fact that the sheaf condition for a sieve implies the sheaf condition for any  "larger" sieve then reduces to a handful of well-known facts:

- The associated sheaf functor $[\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathcal{C}; \mathbf{Set})$ preserves finite limits (hence monomorphisms).
- If $\mathfrak{U}' \subseteq \mathfrak{U} \subseteq \mathcal{C}(-, C)$, then $a \mathfrak{U}' \subseteq a \mathfrak{U} \subseteq a \mathcal{C}(-, C)$; so if $a \mathfrak{U}' = a \mathcal{C}(-, C)$, then $a \mathfrak{U} = a \mathcal{C}(-, C)$.

In some sense, this is just like the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) from calculus.

Incidentally, the principle here is sufficiently general to work in the homotopical setting. So, for instance, one can deduce that a presheaf satisfies the descent condition with respect to bounded hypercovers if and only if it satisifies the descent condition with respect to sieves, etc.